# How can i find the length of dictionary which consists list and again dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.6

Find the length of given list of dictionary

```py
x= {
    'output':[
        {
            'frame':{'enc':1,'time':2}, 'eth':{'di':1,'ghg':5}
        },
    ]
}
```

How can I find the length of 'x' using **Python 3.6.0**
`len(x)` doesn't work I have tried already.
Can anyone suggest an other way?

Comment: What do you expect the return length to be for your example?

Comment: You might want to look into trees, if you want to know how many final children exist in the dictionary or you could recursivley count, or something. its unclear what you really want. Do you want number of children? Number of keys? number of endpoints?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I want to know the number of childrens. The real problem is this output I'm getting when I'm converting .json file  to .pcap file. sometimes the output comes  as **{output:[]}** so In this case i want to run the code again for this undesirable output. Because sometimes the output is expected as above and sometiems the output is blank(    {output:[]}  ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = sum([len(v)+1 for k, v in x.items()])
print((n))
```

This worked for me. After trying to figure out what I actually wanted in return from `len(x)` the above solution came handy.

I took the solution from here: [Get the number of all keys in a dictionary of dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427814/get-the-number-of-all-keys-in-a-dictionary-of-dictionaries-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

we call this normal dictionary where you have your value as list.

printing the length of x works fine for me.

```
x= {'output':[{'frame':{'enc':1,'time':2}, 'eth':{'di':1,'ghg':5}},]}
print(len(x))
```

I am getting output as 1

Explanation:-

you define a dictionary named x which is a dictionary in which you are trying to get the the length of x since it have only one key/value pair i.e 'output' so it will give length of 1 .

if you want to print the length of the list which is treated as the value of output key you can do it like this:-

```
x= {'output':[{'frame':{'enc':1,'time':2}, 'eth':{'di':1,'ghg':5}},]}
print(len(x['output'][0]))
```

you'll get 2 as an output.

if you need further explanation you can comment the same below.

Happy coding :-)

Comment: Thank you for responding. I want to know the number of childrens. The real problem is this output I'm getting when I'm converting .json file to .pcap file. sometimes the output comes as {output:[]} so In this case i want to run the code again for this undesirable output. Because sometimes the output is expected as above and sometiems the output is blank( {output:[]} )

Answer (score 2):

len(x) works fine. What exactly is ur issue?

```
>>> x = {'output':[{'frame':{'enc':1,'time':2}, 'eth':{'di':1,'ghg':5}},]}
>>> len(x)
1
>>> len(x.keys())
1
>>> len(x.values())
1
>>> x.values()
dict_values([[{'frame': {'enc': 1, 'time': 2}, 'eth': {'di': 1, 'ghg': 5}}]])
>>> len(x['output'])
1
>>> x['output']
[{'frame': {'enc': 1, 'time': 2}, 'eth': {'di': 1, 'ghg': 5}}]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I want to know the number of childrens. The real problem is this output I'm getting when I'm converting .json file to .pcap file. sometimes the output comes as {output:[]} so In this case i want to run the code again for this undesirable output. Because sometimes the output is expected as above and sometiems the output is blank( {output:[]} )